# Using GUIDFromString requries including Shell32.dll: How do I do that

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am attempting to use the WinAPI function `GUIDFromString()` but it requires some finagling to include it in my project.

According to the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> This function is not declared in a header or exported by name from a
>   .dll file. It must be loaded from Shell32.dll as ordinal 703 for
>   GUIDFromStringA and ordinal 704 for GUIDFromStringW.
>
> It can also be accessed from Shlwapi.dll as ordinal 269 for
>   GUIDFromStringA and ordinal 270 for GUIDFromStringW.

I have never loaded a DLL before so I am not sure what I should do and I am unsure if loading the DLL is enough, do I also have to include an 'ordinal' with the number 703? Would anyone be able to provide any advice on what I need to do to use this function and even an example?

My attempt below does not work(I am using VC++ 2010 Express):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib") // if I am including the dll do I need to include the lib aswell?

// I've heard that the dll location differs across versions of windows
// Does anyone know of a Cross-Windows-Version way to include Shell32.dll no matter where it is? Maybe use a keyword like "%SYSTEM%/Shell32.dll"
HINSTANCE shell32DLL = LoadLibary("C:/System/Shell32.dll"); 

// Now do I include 'Ordinal 703' as described in msdn? And how do I do that?
```

Comment: I've not done anything of the sort with ordinals instead of names, but I'm guessing you specify `"703"` as the name in `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: You can also use the `UuidFromString` function which is exported by name (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379336(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @chris: use `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` to pass an ordinal to `GetProcAddress()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Oh, I see. That will be good to know one day, thanks.

Comment: Curious, do you know the GUID in advance (vs is this a string you discover at runtime?) - if so, you can skip the string parsing and declare it at compile time as `GUID myGuid = { 0x00000000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }` or similar.

Comment: Even if you do discovery it at runtime, guid strings are fairly common and don't use too many different formats (there are only so many variations you can represent a guid with - hyphens vs commas, braces vs no braces, etc), so you might alternatively consider just parsing the string manually with `sscanf()` or similar.  It really doesn't take that much code to do, if you can't access an OS function for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776431.aspx) for `GUIDFromString()`, it says:

> GUIDFromString is available through Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or Windows Vista. It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Applications should use CLSIDFromString or IIDFromString in place of this function.

[`CLSIDFromString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680589.aspx) and [`IIDFromString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687262.aspx) are both exported by name from Ole32.dll, so you can use them like you would any other DLL function.

With that said, if you still want to use `GUIDFromString()` then use [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) to load shell32.dll and then use [`GetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) to access the function.  [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944.aspx) demonstrates how to do that.  To load a function by ordinal, you can use the [`MAKEINTRESOURCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) macro when calling `GetProcAddress()`.

So, for example:

```
// MAKEINTRESOURCE() returns an LPTSTR, but GetProcAddress()
// expects LPSTR even in UNICODE, so using MAKEINTRESOURCEA()...
#ifdef UNICODE
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEA_T(a, u) MAKEINTRESOURCEA(u)
#else
#define MAKEINTRESOURCEA_T(a, u) MAKEINTRESOURCEA(a)
#endif

BOOL myGUIDFromString(LPCTSTR psz, LPGUID pguid)
{
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;

    typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GUIDFromString)(LPCTSTR, LPGUID);
    LPFN_GUIDFromString pGUIDFromString = NULL;

    HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(TEXT("shell32.dll"));
    if (hInst)
    {
        pGUIDFromString = (LPFN_GUIDFromString) GetProcAddress(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCEA_T(703, 704));
        if (pGUIDFromString)
            bRet = pGUIDFromString(psz, pguid);
        FreeLibrary(hInst);
    }

    if (!pGUIDFromString)
    {
        hInst = LoadLibrary(TEXT("Shlwapi.dll"));
        if (hInst)
        {
            pGUIDFromString = (LPFN_GUIDFromString) GetProcAddress(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCEA_T(269, 270));
            if (pGUIDFromString)
                bRet = pGUIDFromString(psz, pguid);
            FreeLibrary(hInst);
        }
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: Yes I can use COM and OLE without MSVC. For `IIDFromString` make sure that interface IID in enclosed in curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following lines as SHLWAPIX.DEF:

```
LIBRARY SHLWAPI
VERSION 6.0
EXPORTS
 GUIDFromStringA @269
 GUIDFromStringW @270
```

Save the following lines as SHLWAPIX.C:

```
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776431.aspx

__declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall GUIDFromStringA(void *_1, void *_2)
{ return 0; }

__declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall GUIDFromStringW(void *_1, void *_2)
{ return 0; }
```

Run
`CL.EXE /LD /Zl SHLWAPIX.C /link /DEF:SHLWAPIX.DEF /NOENTRY`
to create the import library SHLWAPIX.LIB, then delete SHLWAPIX.OBJ, SHLWAPIX.EXP and SHLWAPIX.DLL

Save the following lines as SHLWAPIX.H:

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(linker, "/DEFAULTLIB:SHLWAPIX.LIB")

__declspec(dllimport)
BOOL WINAPI GUIDFromStringA(LPCSTR psz, LPGUID pguid);

__declspec(dllimport)
BOOL WINAPI GUIDFromStringW(LPCWSTR psz, LPGUID pguid);
```

Finally save the following lines as SHLWAPIX.C:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "SHLWAPIX.LIB")
#pragma comment(lib, "USER32.LIB")

#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup")
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.0")
#pragma comment(linker, "/VERSION:1.0")

#define STRICT
#define UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include "shlwapix.h"

VOID wWinMainCRTStartup()
{
    GUID guid = {0};
    WCHAR szBuffer[1025] = L"";

    if (GUIDFromStringA("{00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}", &guid))
        if (wsprintf(szBuffer, L"GUID = {%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}\n",`
                     guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]) > 0)
            MessageBox((HWND) NULL, szBuffer, L"GUIDFromStringA()", MB_OK);

    if (GUIDFromStringW(L"{FFEEDDCC-BBAA-9988-7766-554433221100}", &guid))
        if (wsprintf(szBuffer, L"GUID = {%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}\n",
                     guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]) > 0)
            MessageBox((HWND) NULL, szBuffer, L"GUIDFromStringW()", MB_OK);
}
```

Finally run `CL.EXE /GS- SHLWAPIX.C` to create SHLWAPIX.EXE, then run the latter.

Answer (score 0):

This gives your an error "syntax error '('":

```
typedef BOOL WINAPI (*LPFN_GUIDFromString)(LPCTSTR, LPGUID);
```

The proper version is:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_GUIDFromString)(LPCTSTR, LPGUID);
```

Comment: An answer is not the proper area to comment another answer, but anyway ... it is helpful.