# Generating UID of windows computer

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have some long strings. Each strings contain information of a windows computer (computer name, MAC address etc). I want to generate 8 character long UIDs from those strings. How I can generate that ? Is there any C++ library or method to do that.

Comment: you can see here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555591/using-guidfromstring-requries-including-shell32-dll-how-do-i-do-that

Comment: What do you want to do with the GUID? A GUID is not a hash value, so you cannot create it from something else than a GUID (or a representation thereof). A GUID is, simply speaking, just a random value.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`GUIDFromString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to converts a `string` to a `GUID`.

```
BOOL GUIDFromString(
  _In_   LPCTSTR psz,
  _Out_  LPGUID pguid
);
```

Alternatively, you can try [`CLSIDFromString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680589%28VS.85%29.aspx.aspx). A `CLSID` is actually defined as:

```
typedef GUID CLSID;
```

therefore you can use `CLSIDFromString` to generate a GUID. Here's some sample code:

```
LPWSTR guidstr;
GUID guid;

...

HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(guidstr, (LPCLSID)&guid);
if (hr != S_OK) {
    // bad GUID string...
    ...
}
```

Comment: but how to use that inside my c++ program ?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: `CLSIDFromString` creates a guid from the string representation of one, not from an arbitrary string. It is _not_ a hash function.